# How to inspect a jQuery object in Firebug like IE's debugger?

Tags: jquery, firebug

in IE I can view the structure of a jQuery object in an expandable treeview. How do I get something similar  in Firefox's Firebug?

**Addition:**
The top dark box shows the object in IE. The bottom shows the same object in Firebug (pretty empty!).

[image]

Comment: You might want to look into FireQuery. It's a Firebug extension for working with jQuery. Very handy if you work with jQuery a lot. Url here: http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Comment: Not sure how FireQuery helps here. it's more for looking at events bindings & data. Not sure how to use it to inspect a jquery object properties beyond what Firebug provides.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich, hey. Can you tell me please what's the name of IE debugger on your screenshot? Because i tired of default F12 debugger

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "DOM" tab and in there will be listed a bunch of variables and objects and others. Find your jQuery object and you can navigate its content.

I hope this helps.

Hrsto

Comment: It's a local variable in a function. It doesn't show in the DOM tab (or I don't know how to get to it there). In shows in the watch subtab in the SCRIPT tab and it's 'jQuery( ul )'. If I click on 'ul', it jumps to its representation in the html. I want to look at the properties like ID property.

Comment: I'm not sure about that... maybe check out FireQuery: http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Answer (score 0):

Enter your variable or expression into the watch window or use the DOM tab as others have mentioned.

[image]

Comment: I have a line like: var $list = $("ul") and a breakpoint after it. In the Watch tab, the '+' for $list doesn't expand to anything. In IE's debugger, there's one object, [0], and I can look at its properties. The same object is not showing in firebug. nothing to expand for $list. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you paste $list into the yellow bar "new watch expression" as you see in the screenshot above?

Comment: I added a screenshot. I pasted $list (the non bolded one)

Comment: What version of FireBug and Firefox are you using, and have you enabled the console and script tabs of FireBug? Also make sure FireBug is open and refresh your page to make sure it's in full debugging mode.

Comment: Firefox 3.6.13, Firebug 1.7, FireQuery 0.8. All the latest. The console & script tabs are enabled. I refreshed the page many times and restarted Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try the triangle in the watch tab, it will have options for what to show. Be sure the show user properties and show user functions are enabled...